# Iterating over Observable values and subscribe to new Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Let's say if have an `Array` inside an `Observable`, for each value of that array, it want to make an API call (which returns an `Observable` again). I'll break it down to a simple example. Because I need to iterate over the first `observables` values, how do I make sure that `data` contains the actual data, and not another observable?

I tried `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, etc..

```
const observables = Observable.of([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);
const data = Observable.of('data');

observables.pipe(

  // I tried a lot, something like this
  map(values => {
    if(Array.isArray(values)) {
      values.map(value => value.data = data); // data will be an Observable
    }
    return values;
  })

).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result) // I want: [{ id: 1, data: 'data' }, { ... }]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending upon your requirement of sending API requests you could use any of mergeMap, concatMap, forkJoin, etc.

I will be giving an example using `forkJoin` and `mergeMap`

```js
const observableData: Observable<{ id: number; data?: any }[]> = of([
  { id: 11 },
  { id: 12 }
]);

return observableData.pipe(
  mergeMap(values => {
    // first map all the observales to make an array for API calls
    let apiArray = values.map(eachValue => {
      return this.yourApiService.getData(eachValue.id);
    });
    // now you have to make API calls
    return forkJoin(...apiArray).pipe(
      map(apiData => {
        // now modify your result to contain the data from API
        // apiData will be an array conating results from API calls
        // **note:** forkJoin will return the data in the same sequence teh requests were sent so doing a `forEach` works here
        values.forEach((eachOriginalValue, index) => {
          eachOriginalValue.data = apiData[index].name; // use the key in which you get data from API
        });
        return values;
      }),
      catchError(e => {
        console.log("error", e);
        return of(e);
      })
    );
  })
);
```

See a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/forkjoinwithmergemap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot, also great working example! This seems to do the trick

Comment: @AicoKleinOvink: Glad, could help!